# Get specific XML element attributes in Labview

Tags: xml, labview

I have an XML document of the type

```
<exp>
    <header>
        <expID description="experiment type">0001</expID>
        <expTime unit="minutes">10000</expTime>
    </header>
</exp>
```

I would like to extract the description attribute from Labview. I (in form of Labview) know the name of the attribute as well as in which node it is. However, I am having difficulties of getting the node attributes, in this case of`<expID>`. I read that it should be possible using the invoke node for `Element`but I cannot find a way to convert the node into an element.[image: Labview code]

I found [this information](https://forums.ni.com/t5/LabVIEW/Xml-Attributes/m-p/1457370#M556089) but it only seems to work using `//@*`, not for a specific node or specific attribute. Is there a simple way to get a specific attribute from a node?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is to have the attribute identifier (@) as part of the XPath expression:

[image]

/exp/header/expID/@description

and then the attribute will be returned as a node reference (or an array of node references, in your case) and you can use the Get Node Text Content VI to get the data.

In general, when dealing with XML, you'll want to look up XPath syntax.

Comment: How do you modify this to return an array of node references? For example if <expID description=""> was repeated multiple times, how would I capture all values that exist into an array?

Comment: You would use the **Get All Matched Nodes** VI, which returns an array of references of all the matches, then iterate over those references.

Answer (score 0):

I found a semi-solution by playing around with the node values. I still don't find it very intuitive. [image: Labview snippet]

Comment: Could you share the rest of your VI before this For loop? I have a similar problem so I tried replicating this code, but Im getting a "Tried to perform an Xpath Query on an invalid node refnum" error on the "Get matched nodes" function prior to the For Loop.

Comment: I solved my problem using this method with LibXML2: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45420058/libxml-with-labview-no-namespace-prefix - maybe it could work for you?