# LibXML with Labview - no namespace prefix

Tags: xml, xpath, libxml2, labview

I have been using Labview's native XML parser to read an XML document. As it turns out, it is too slow for large files. I therefore am trying to use [LibXML](http://forums.ni.com/t5/Example-Program-Drafts/Parsing-XML-is-too-slow-or-is-it/ta-p/3492686) as it seems to be quite popular. However, I am having trouble with namespaces. I have a third-party XML document that comes like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<foo xmlns="urn:foo_Schema_V3">
     <bar>
        <fooID description="XML Test 170731"></fooID>
        <barNumber>60</barNumber>      
    </bar>
</foo>
```

and would like to select the *barNumber* using Labview which uses XPath.
[image: Labview Code]

The content text should be *60*, however it remains empty. I read up a little and assume this is due to namespace issues in LibXML. As a test, I changed the second line in XML to

```
<foo xmlns:cliff="urn:foo_Schema_V3">
```

suddenly, the XPath expression works even though *cliff* is never even mentioned in Labview.

**Q**: How can I select the node I want without having a namespace prefix?

**Update:** I have taken to using 
    `/*[local-name()='foo']/*[local-name()='bar']/*[local-name()=‌​'barNumber']`, which is not elegant and does not explain **WHY** a node is not selectable without prefix.