# LabVIEW Parsing XML String without using tools

Tags: labview

I am creating an information displaying mini-app for a device. The response I receive from the device when I send an HTTP Get request is literally as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-2"?>
<root xmlns="http://www.papouch.com/xml/th2e/act">
<sns id="1" type="1" status="0" unit="0" val="25.0" w-min="" w-max="" e-min-val="      -0.3" e-max-val="     124.0" e-min-dte="01/01/2014 13:16:44" e-max-dte="05/14/2014 10:00:43" /><sns id="2" type="2" status="0" unit="3" val="56.4" w-min="" w-max="" e-min-val="       0.1" e-max-val="     100.0" e-min-dte="01/27/2014 08:39:14" e-max-dte="03/04/2014 11:02:40" /><sns id="3" type="3" status="0" unit="0" val="15.7" w-min="" w-max="" e-min-val="     -21.3" e-max-val="      85.9" e-min-dte="01/27/2014 12:21:28" e-max-dte="03/04/2014 11:29:32" /><status frm="1" location="NONAME" time="01/02/2014  7:12:00" typesens="3" /></root>
```

There are 3 sns elements with incrementing `id`s, I need to read the `val` attribute of the sns element with the `id` `1`.

I tried implementing the suggested way here:[Get specific XML element attributes in Labview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43739672/get-specific-xml-element-attributes-in-labview) , and shown below is [my implementation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zXuzW.png), but it does not work. I tested the XPath on http://xpather.com/ and it fetches the value I need just fine.

The XPath I am using is: `//root/sns[@id="1"]/@val`

The result I get when I run is just nothing, no Parsing errors, no any other errors, everything seems to be okay but the `String` indicator is always empty, `String 2` displays the HTTP response fine.

I am using (and have to use) LabVIEW 2011 SP1.

[image: My implementation]

Comment: In the other thread that you are referring to the `Get First Matched Node VI` is used. Have you tried the same without `[@id="1"]`?

Comment: If I take the code from the other question and simply paste both your XML and your XPath into the constants there, I get 25.0 in the indicator (this is in LV 2011), so this does work. My guess would be that either the XML you're getting is not the XML you showed, or you have a parsing error or just an error on the error wire (maybe you don't have auto error handling on), etc.

Comment: @Yair I hoped you would see my post! Error handling for "newly created VI" were turned off. I turned them on and copied the things across.. I am still not getting any errors internally, nor any windows popping up. I am really confused.

Comment: @Markus Yes I am using Get First Matched Node. The icon is slightly different probably because I am using a different version. I have tried without the id, even without sns just to take the root out but nothing.

Comment: @Yair As a side note, I get the text every time it runs, so that is definitely the text I am getting. But just in case, I also set up a String consonant instead of an HTTP Get request, I also tried it with a simplified version of it by including only `val` and `id` attributes of `sns` elements. Still nothing..

Comment: Check if the example from the other question works as-is. If it does, paste your values in and check if it works (it did for me). If it doesn't, maybe there's something wrong with your XML DLL? I don't see how, but things happen. If the other example worked and your code doesn't, then you can try to figure out what the difference is.

Comment: @Yair I have created a brand new VI, and did it exactly the same shown in your example - it does not work.. Any idea how I can fix the DLL, except uninstalling and re-installing it back again?

Comment: On the slow run, error in/out wires show OK, and I see no Parse Errors in the indicator I connected to it.

Comment: Don't recreate the code in other question manually. It's a snippet, so you should be able to save the image and then drag the file into a block diagram and get back the original code. That way, you can be sure you're testing the same thing.

Comment: @Yair Oh that's amazing! I had no idea I could do that!! Thank you so much. I will try and build the rest of my program around your snippet. I was getting so frustrated. Thanks a lot for the help.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why the result is empty is the wrong input of Get Node Text Content.

[image: corrected program]